# Suppressing negative elements of an array

Tags: arrays, element, negative-number

I'm writing a code which suppresses or pushes the negative elements of an int array to the bottom of the array, without altering the sequence of the rest of the array. Which basically means it is not the mere sorting of the array. So far I've got this:

```
class supparray
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    { 
        int array1Index = 0, array2Index = 0;
        int array[] = {1, -8, 5, 12, -6, 2, 4};
        int length = array.length;
        int array1[] = new int[length] ;
        int array2[] = new int[length];
        for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++)
        {
            if(array[i]<0)
            {

                array1[i] = array[i];
                array1Index+=1;
            }
            else
            {
                array2[i] = array[i];
                array2Index+=1;
            }
            for(int j = 0; j<array2Index; j++)
            {
                array1[array1Index+j] = array2[j];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(array1);
    }


}
```

So, the code compiles, but I'm getting a very weird output. Like, it doesn't even have only numbers. My output is:
[I@104c575
I really have no idea as to what's wrong. Is it my logic, or is my JDK really messed up?
TIA.

Comment: Since you asked about your JDK, I'm assuming this is Java, not C#. Is that correct? I recommend you add the language you're using to the question tags.

Comment: Also, calling `println` on an array doesn't print the array.

Comment: Yes, I am using Java. Will remember to add Java as a question tag next time. Just thought that the syntax would tell that I use Java. Anyway, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two answers here. First is the answer to your code. You must properly format an array.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));
```

The second answer is just another approach to your problem. It's a bit cleaner and more efficient, and at least checks to make sure your array is longer than 1 before beginning to manipulate.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class supparray
{
public static int array[] = {1, -8, 5, 12, -6, 2, 4};
public static int storage=0;
public static void main(String args[])
{ 
    int length = array.length;
    System.out.println (length);
    if (length>1)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<(length-1); i++)
        {
            if (array[i]<0)
            {
                storage=array[i];
                for (int j = 0; j<(length-i-1);j++)
                {
                    array[i+j]=array[i+j+1];
                }
            array[length-1]=storage;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
}
```

Comment: Okay. I kind of understand. But, can you explain where I went wrong with my code?

Comment: An array is a specific data structure that cannot be printed out, you see the resulting jumble. Another way to print out an array would be a for loop that displays one element at a time ex: for int i=0;i <length; i++ then inside the loop print (array [i] + " ");,which prints the number at that position in the array and then a space.  Be sure to use print, not println.

Comment: Got it. It works fine now. So basically, I got the printing part wrong, and my logic, though clumsy, is technically correct, right?

Comment: That's correct. Your code is fine, except for the printing. An array needs to be manipulated in some way to be in a state that can be printed out legibly.